# Removed Target Module in my Swift Xcode 7 project and now getting error about info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode7

I recently added a new Target.  I decided that this was the wrong way to add what I needed so I deleted it.  This has cause problems and I cant figure out how to resolve them.  I removed the target from Target Dependencies, Link Binary With Libraries, and Embed Frameworks under Build Phases.  I am currently not building and getting this error:

could not read data from '/Users/jameshollyer/Development/IOS/WXPG/PTSMessage/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Obviously it cannot read it because that file is not there...but it should not try to read it.  How do I stop it from trying to read this file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I solved this problem finally by clicking around enough.  If you are having a similar problem open up your .xcodeproj file and then expand the page on the left side by clicking this button
[image]

Then in the list of targets below you will see the target that you deleted.  Just right click it and delete it from there.

Hope this helps someone!

Happy Coding!